# homogeneous nonlinear functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Give an example of degree one positively homogeneous function, (i.e. a function $f$, such that $\forall \alpha\ge0, f(\alpha x) =\alpha f(x)$)  that is not linear, and $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is this a homework? Hint: What degree does the square of such a function have?

Comment: It is not a homework, it came up in the middle of a bigger problem. :-)

Comment: When you ask about degree, you assume it is a polynomial?

Comment: Well, I of course meant homogeneous degree, but I was indeed thinking ultimately of a very simple polynomial. But since it's not a homework, I'll just write the answer in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example would be $f(x)=\left|x\right|$.

About the hint in my comment: For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\left|x\right| = \sqrt{x^2}$.

Actually the most general function with the desired property would be $f(x)=\alpha x+\beta\left|x\right|$ with $\alpha, \beta \in\mathbb{R}$ arbitrary real constants.