# When do two quantities follow the unitary method?

Tags: ratio

I was learning about angle systems and encountered this simple argument :
$$90^o = 1 \text{ right angle }$$
$$\implies 1^o = \Bigg(\dfrac{1}{90}\Bigg)^{th} \text{ of a right angle}$$
Seems obvious, doesn't it? This got me wondering : "When do two quantities that are somehow related to each other follow the unitary method?"

Let's say that if first quantity is $x$, then the second quantity is given by a function, $f$. If they follow the unitary method, it means that for $n \in \Bbb R$, $f(nx) = n\cdot f(x)$. Now, for what kind of functions is this true?

I know that one of these might be : $f(x) = kx$ which would imply that $f(nx) = k(nx) = n(kx) = n\cdot f(x)$.

But, are other functions that satisfy this relation possible as well? If yes, please provide some examples and if no, is there some proof that no such function exists?

Thank You.

Comment: Maybe this:  [linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity#In_mathematics)

Comment: Functions which satisfy $f(nx) = n\cdot f(x)$ are called [homogeneous of degree 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function).  You may also be interested in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406163/homogeneous-nonlinear-functions) question.

Comment: To comment on the above, all linear maps are homogeneous of degree 1, but not all homogeneous functions are linear.

Comment: So, homogeneous functions of degree $1$ satisfy $f(nx) = n\cdot f(x)$. Are there any other functions that do the same?

Comment: $f(kx)=kf(x)$ is the *definition* of "homogeneous of degree one," Rajdeep. If such a function is *continuous*, then it must be of the form $f(x)=ax$ for some $a$. There are discontinuous examples, but they are complicated, and rely on the Axiom of Choice for their construction. You'll probably find expositions of these facts in the links that have been provided to you. Read them!

Comment: Have you had a chance to follow up on those links, Rajdeep?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. I did check them out and they did clarify my doubts...

Comment: Good. Do you want to write up an answer, and post it? or maybe you want to have your question closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't see this question helping any future visitors and since it indeed is, in a way, a duplicate, I'd say it's better to close it...

Comment: OK, why don't you flag it for closure?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Done...